# How do I easily convert a Unity project from Oculus Rift DK 1 to Oculus Rift DK 2?

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

I was the developer on a project using Oculus Rift about 2 months ago. I received the Oculus DK 2 now and I want to update the project. I've been thinking to what it could be the easiest way but I want to be sure I don't miss something I could try before going for the hardest approach which means wiping out the DK 1 objects like OVRCamera and all the links to it, go through all the scenes and update everything component by component, and so on.

What I tried so far (not caring about dumbness):

1. Import DK2 package on top of DK1
2. Delete whole DK1's OVR folder from inside Unity and import DK2 (which creates OVR folder again)
3. Delete whole DK1's OVR folder and paste DK2's OVR folder, all done from Explorer

So, I ended up with loads of errors in all cases which, I know, is a bit obvious but was still worthy a try.

**Do you have any other clever ideas to try?**

Thank you all for your attention.

Comment: Hi there, Did you get the DK2 to work with your application?

Comment: Hi, yes. Making DK2 work is quite easy. To convert from DK1 though I had to switch to DirectX 11*, which, basing on the project, can imply quite some work in fixing shaders. *: DX11 must be used when you want to be in direct mode and still see the image on your monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a similar problem to you. I fixed it by removing all the DK1 OVR files, then importing the Tuscany demo, then copying the OVRPlayerController from their scene into mine, then moved scripts from my old OVRPlayerController, to the new one. finished up with no errors relating to the PlayerController

Comment: Hi, When you say "moved scripts from my old OVRPlayerController to the new one" do you mean you just deleted the newly-imported file and copied the old one?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1) Open up a blank scene in your DK1 project. 
2) Delete the OVR folder in Assets
3) Delete the three files with the word 'oculus' in it in the Plugin folder in Assets.

Import "OculusUnityIntegration.unitypackage" from the Oculus website.

Some adjustments were required from there (replacing Character Controllers and stuff like that), but ultimately it worked!